# Missing or blocked gclid tracking

Tags: cookies, google-tag-manager, google-ads-api, google-analytics-4

I've setup Google Ads account to auto-tag. (provide a gclid)  I've used Google Tag Manager for setting up the Google Ads tags and the GA4 tags. All of this works when testing it in Chrome.  I know it does not work when I click on one of my own ads while in Firefox using strict security settings.  I've also heard that some popular ad blockers can be enabled to block Google Tag Manager.  I currently have no software installed for requesting cookie permissions.  I had some, but removed it to try to solve this problem.

I don't expect the gclid to be present all the time since I know of some scenarios when it will not work, but in the last week Google Ads said there were 15 clicks on my ads, but only 1 time did Google Analytics record a gclid. Does anyone have any ideas about what could be causing the lack of gclids?

Another potential problem I know of is website redirects.  I don't have any known redirects and I did already identify and remove an accidental redirect that was happening because my page was called https://www.goalalignedmedia.com/gamlp-education-marketing-part-1.html and I'd left off the ".html" in Google Ads.  Consequently the website was implicitly "redirecting" to the .html version.  I don't think redirects are the problem at this point.

Thanks in advance for any help.
Dave

Comment: `but only 1 time did Google Analytics record a gclid.` Curious about where you review the data?